# Put every 1st and every 2nd div in different div

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

```
<div id="posts">
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
</div>
```

And what i want is this:

```
<div id="posts">
<div id="postsLeft">
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
</div>
<div id="postsRight">
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So i want to every first class post put to postLeft and every secound class post put to postRight. The reason why i dont sort them by myself is because i use ajax and div class post is loading when user wants to get more posts. Script must work with this script http://jsfiddle.net/tq6a202n/1/

Comment: What do you have so far and where do you get stuck? Also, wouldn't a simple `.post:nth-child(even) {float:right}` do the trick?

Comment: How do you determine whether something is first class or second class? It is clear that in the result you differentiate by their inner text, but how do you differentiate from ajax response?

Comment: This was my first option but it didnt work well

Comment: I dont know how to determine when is first when is secound

Comment: How would you determine logically?

Comment: Count all divs class post from div posts and when is odd put post to postsLeft and when is even put post to postsRight

Comment: _"Script must work with this script"_ appear different from original Question  _"Put every 1st and every 2nd div in different div"_ , _"want to every first class post put to postLeft and every secound class post put to postRight. "_ ?

Comment: yes i was thingking it will work with my script but didnt

Answer (score 0):

A possible way - you can add following code

```
var postsLeft = $("<div></div>"); // create wrapper for left
var postsRight = $("<div></div>"); // create wrapper for right
postsLeft.attr("id", "postsLeft"); // add id for left
postsRight.attr("id", "postsRight"); // add id for right
var counter = 0; // counter to check for even and odd
$("#posts").find("div.post").each(function(){ // iterate over post elements
    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
        postsLeft.append($(this).clone()); // For odd append here
    } else {
        postsRight.append($(this).clone()); // For even append here

    }
    counter++; // update counter

});

$("#posts").html(""); // Empty div
$("#posts").append(postsLeft); // Append left div
$("#posts").append(postsRight); // Append right div
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/qIip2X8rTKi8naFiM27y?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

> Your Answer here with working example :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#posts').append('<div id="postsLeft"></div><div id="postsRight"></div>');
    $('#posts div').not('#postsLeft,#postsRight').each(function () {
        if($(this).text()=='1st'){
           $(this).appendTo('#posts #postsLeft');
        }else{
            $(this).appendTo('#posts #postsRight');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="posts">
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `:even` selector , `.prependTo()` , `.wrapAll()`

```js
$("<div />", {"id":"postsLeft", "html":$("#posts .post:even")})
.prependTo("#posts").siblings(".post").wrapAll("<div id=postsRight />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="posts">
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
<div class="post">1st</div>
<div class="post">2nd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @fr33jumper _"This works but not for this script"_ , _"Script must work with this script http://jsfiddle.net/tq6a202n/1/"_  not included at original Question ? See also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218206/put-every-1st-and-every-2nd-div-in-different-div/31218380?noredirect=1#comment50437468_31218206  _"Count all divs class post from div posts and when is odd put post to postsLeft and when is even put post to postsRight"_ `html` not included , jQuery not appear loaded at http://jsfiddle.net/tq6a202n/1/ ; `php` does not run at jsfiddle